# DISTINCT keyword on two different table's content

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we use DISTINCT keyword on two different table's content created by FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Yes you site can, DISTINCT simply removes any duplicates from the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, or even on three tables:

```
select  distinct t1.id, t2.col1, t3.col1
from    table1 t1
full outer join
        table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.t1_id
full outer join
        table3 t3
on      t1.id = t3.t1_id
```